# Is it fine to use logs in the Helper Methods?

Tags: java, java-ee, logging

I have been doubting for a long time whether or not to have a logger in methods (usually helper methods) like the one below.

Whether we can print it in the method or print the response where the method is called.

```
public String getAddNewUserUrl()
{
    String url      =   null;
    String mode     =   null;
    try
    {
        log.info("Inside getAddNewUserUrl "); // Can u use logs like this.
        mode        =   new ModeUtil().getMode();

        if("local".equalsIgnoreCase(mode) || "staging".equalsIgnoreCase(mode))
        {
            url     =   ResourceBundle.getBundle("ApplicationResources").getString("staging.url");
        }
        else
        {
            url     =   ResourceBundle.getBundle("ApplicationResources").getString("staging.url");  
        }
        log.info("The url is  : " + url);  // Can u use logs like this

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.info("Exception in the method getMode ::"+e.getMessage());
    }
    return url;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logs are supposed to be put in every part of your application to provide meaningful information to developer/tester/debuggers or any other stake holder.

Just be careful to put appropriate logging level in your helper classes/utilities especially if you going to distribute it as jar.

Comment: I'd add that it's good to be judicious with logging. In addition to setting the correct logging level, it's important to think about _why_ you're doing the logging, and whether you'll glean (or regret missing) some crucial piece of information at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

It's ok to have logging in every part of your application, even in the helper methods, if you can set different logging levels.

```
log.info("The url is  : " + url, LogLevel.Debug);
```

This ensures that you can turn it on or off depending on how much info you want to gather.
Having it always on, that's not so smart.

Comment: can I use ? 
log.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,e.getMessage(),e);

Comment: yes, that's for stuff like exceptions that shouldn't happen, i.e. your database connection is down or some file that's supposed to be there isn't.